# Django - Legacy database tables - Querying 2 one to many tables

Tags: django, one-to-many

I am new to Django and would like some advice on how to query from 3 tables.

I have 3 tables from legacy database mapped in to models (`Patient`, `PrescribedMeds`, `PrescribedMedsSchedule`).  We can't change this structure since this will have to remain active while we create the Django application.

1 patient can have many prescribed medication.
1 prescribed medication can have several times in the schedule

Below is the model in django.

## models.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    patient_name = models.CharField(db_column='patient_name', max_length=50)  
    dob = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DOB', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    gender = models.CharField(db_column='Gender', max_length=7)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dateofentry = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateOfEntry', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ....
    ....

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'patient'
    
    def __str__(self):
            return self.patient_name

class PrescribedMeds(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    patient_id= models.ForeignKey(Patient, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='patient_id')
    med_type = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='Type')  # Field name made lowercase.
    name_of_medication = models.CharField(db_column='Name_Of_Medication', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    rxno = models.CharField(db_column='RxNo', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    date_filled = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateFilled', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ....
    ....

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'prescribed_meds'
    
    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id) + ", " + self.name_of_medication + ", " + str(self.childno)

class PrescribedMedsSchedule(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    prescribed_meds_id = models.ForeignKey(PrescribedMeds, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='prescribed_meds_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    medication_date = models.DateField()
    medication_time = models.DateTimeField()
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    form = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'prescribed_meds_schedule'
```

I am trying to get the right syntax in Django to display data from the 3 columns (`Prescribed_Meds.ID`, `PrescribedMeds.name_of_medication`, `Patient.patient_name`, `PrescribedMedsSchedule.medication_date`, `PrescribedMedsSchedule.medication_time`).

In SQL the query would be

```
SELECT prescribed_meds.ID, prescribed_meds.Name_Of_Medication, patient.patient_name, prescribed_meds_schedule.medication_date, prescribed_meds_schedule.medication_time
FROM prescribed_meds_schedule 
INNER JOIN (prescribed_meds INNER JOIN patient ON prescribed_meds.patient_id = patient.id) ON prescribed_meds_schedule.prescribed_meds_ID = prescribed_meds.ID;
```

What would be the correct query in Django?  I am having an issue since there is no relationship from `PrescribedMedsSchedule` to `Patient` table.

I have tried the following:

```
my_obj = PrescribedMedsSchedule.objects.all().selected_related(
    'prescribed_meds_id'
).prefetch_related('PrescribedMeds__patient_id')
```

However, this query does not bring up the `Patient` table/model.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth starting with a note on what django does internally with a FK. You have a suffix in your models of `_id` but django will do this to the database column automatically. So in your model you could have an easier to read field, `patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)` and it will be `patient_id` in the database.

[`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) follows foreign-key relationships, so you're right to do that. If you want to **INNER join** you should follow the foreign-keys. In your case use the 
[double-underscore](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to get through the models:

```
PrescribedMedsSchedule.objects.all().select_related(
    'prescribed_meds_id'
).select_related('prescribed_meds_id__patient_id')
```

Or you could use 2 queries and use the `id` values from `PrescribedMeds` to then query `PrescribedMedsSchedule`. That would be something like;

```
meds = PrescribedMeds.objects.all().select_related('patient_id')

med_ids = meds.values_list('id', flat=True)

schedules = PrescribedMedsSchedule.objects.filter(prescribed_meds_id__in=med_ids)
```

Comment: markwalker - Thank you very much for your answer.  Your first suggestion worked, and returned exactly the same amount of rows as the SQL query. 

I haven't used your second version, but I will keep that code in my notes.